# cannot change color of timestamped geojson marker using folium

Tags: python, folium

I created a timestamped geojson file to plot markers in a map as follows:

```
def create_geojson_features(df):
    features = []
    for lat,lan,intensity,time in zip(df['latitude'],df['longitude'],df['intensity'],df['timestamp']):

        time = str(time)
        feature = {
            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
                'type':'Point', 
                'coordinates':[lan,lat]
            },
            'properties': {'time':time,'marker-color':'red','iconstyle':{'marker-color':'red'}

            }
        }
        features.append(feature)
    return features
features = create_geojson_features(df)





from folium.plugins import TimestampedGeoJson
m = folium.Map([latmean,lonmean], zoom_start=11)
TimestampedGeoJson(
        {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': features}
        , period='PT1H'
        , duration= 'PT1H'
        , add_last_point=True
        , auto_play=False
        , loop=False
        , max_speed=1
        , loop_button=True
        , date_options='YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'
        , time_slider_drag_update=True
    ).add_to(m)
```

I tried different things like 'style', 'iconColor' but non seem to work, the only color I am getting in each markers is blue. Could you please help?

Comment: Please, provide full code. Thanks.

Comment: @sentence I have uploaded the full code without dataframe, I hope its understandable. Thanks!